# `docker build` hangs based on order of install

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, cmake

Given this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN set -ex && apt-get update

RUN set -ex && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git

RUN set -ex && \
    apt-get install -y \
    cmake

ENV HOME_DIR /home/develop

WORKDIR ${HOME_DIR}
```

The `docker build` hangs configuring `tzdata`:

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -f Docker/Dockerfile -t cmake:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  161.8kB
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 7e0aa2d69a15
Step 2/6 : RUN set -ex && apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 78e8a28063b0
Step 3/6 : RUN set -ex &&     apt-get install -y    git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d400fc509ae8
Step 4/6 : RUN set -ex &&     apt-get install -y    cmake
 ---> Running in 2c58632e70a3
+ apt-get install -y cmake
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
...
Setting up tzdata (2021a-0ubuntu0.20.04) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
  2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
  3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
```

If I reverse the order of `git` and `cmake` it will successfully build.  Why would order matter?

I'm running Docker 20.10.5 on MacOS 11 (Big Sur).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppress prompting from apt by setting the DEBIAN_FRONTEND variable, which can be done with a build arg that only exists during the build (allowing interactive users exec'd into a container):

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN set -ex && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git

RUN set -ex && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    cmake

ENV HOME_DIR /home/develop

WORKDIR ${HOME_DIR}
```

Also, note that the update should be run with the install step to avoid stale caches from breaking builds.

Answer (score 4):

The CMake package must silently pick a default selection for `tzdata` before it is installed (as a dependency of git?). Odd, but the workaround is easy enough. Add the following lines near the top of your `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf "/usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ" /etc/localtime
RUN echo "$TZ" > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
```

Naturally, replace `America/Los_Angeles` with whichever timezone you believe is most appropriate for your application, maybe `UTC`.

Answer (score 1):

Git installs perl as one of its dependencies, and that installs the `Term::ReadLine` perl module as well. With this module, when installing cmake, debconf can initialize the `Readline` frontend, and can wait for input. But if you install cmake first, this module doesn't exist yet locally, and debconf will fail to setup tzdata, and will use the default configuration.

The above is proven by the logs, if we install cmake first:

```
Setting up tzdata (2021a-0ubuntu0.20.04) ...
[243/1270]debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Configuring tzdata
------------------
Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.
1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 111.
Current default time zone: '/UTC'
Local time is now:      Sat May  8 21:19:41 UTC 2021.
Universal Time is now:  Sat May  8 21:19:41 UTC 2021.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.
```

Answer (score 0):

On my `MacOS Catalina version 10.15.7` and `Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d`

I added this in my `Dockerfile` and it works well without hanging

`RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get update && apt-get -y install tzdata`